# Spring AOP creating issues with beans autowiring

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ResponseTimeLoggerAspect {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getCanonicalName());

    @Around("requestHandlerMethod()")
    public void logResponseTime(ProceedingJoinPoint point) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            point.proceed();
        }
        catch (Throwable e) {
        }
        long timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        logger.info(point.getSignature().getName() + " took " + timeTaken + " ms.");
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.jms.JMSMessageListener.*(..))")
    public void requestHandlerMethod() {}
}

@Configuration
@Import({JMSConfig.class, Neo4jConfig.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses=BeansPackageMarker.class)
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class ApplicationConfig {

}
```

**Exception:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.jms.JMSMessageListener] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

If I disable the aspect by commenting out `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` from the `ApplicationConfig`, it doesn't throw any exception but no aspectJ advice is executed (as expected).

It seems to me that by enabling aspectJ, Spring recognizes that the advice is applicable to `JMSMessageListener` so it creates a proxy around it and that's why Spring is not able to autowire `JMSMessageListener` bean because now that bean is not there but the proxy over that bean is there.

Comment: Try to add proxy target `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)`

Comment: @Evgeni It worked. One more issue. I have two methods in `JMSMessageListener` viz. `public void onMessage(Message message) {...}` and `public void handleFriendOfEvent(Message message) {...}`. I want to apply point cuts to only methods which starts with `handle`.. but this pointcut is not working `@Pointcut("execution(* com.jms.JMSMessageListener.handle*(..))")` but this is working `@Pointcut("execution(* com.jms.JMSMessageListener.*(..))")` but on `onMessage()` method..

Comment: Sorry, can't help for the second issue `handle*(..)` looks OK to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As correctly pointed out by @Evgeni, it worked by changing

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
```

to

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
```

which enables CGLIB based proxies (by default DynamicJDK based proxies are enabled)

Also the target class must have a default constructor. It's a requirement for CGLIB based proxies to work.

Comment: You can accept your own answer and close the question.